# How to get contents of multiple elements and append to a div (angular)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My app has two sections, an input section and a "view" section. Its basically an email code generator that uses predefined templates for each section of the email. What I am trying to do is take the contents from the code samples as they are updated, and put them within the view div and render them. Here is a simplified version of the input:

```
<div controller="myController">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="myinput" ng-model="textinput"/>
    </div>
    <xmp type="banner" codeinject></xmp>
</div>
```

This is the directive to inject the email code into the xmp tags:

```
app.directive('codeinject', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return 'partials/email-code/'+attr.type+'.html';
    }
  };
})
```

and here is a sample of what an xmp tag (to fit this example) might look like:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td align="center" valign="middle">{{ textinput }}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue I am having is that I can't figure out a way to take the content from each `<xmp>` tag and append it to my viewing element. Elements can be reorganized, deleted, and added, so any solutions should take that into account. Could this be something as simple as creating a new directive to attach the the `<xmp>` tags? I have tried `ng-change` but because it is not an input element it doesn't work.

Maybe a solution would be to add a variable to the `$rootScope`, and add the contents of each `<xmp>` to that variable and `ng-bind-html` the final result to the view?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution and figured I would post it in case anyone else stumbles upon this issue. You have to create a service, and then add a `$broadcast` event every time an element (`<xmp>` in this case) is updated or created. after that you create an array within the service, and push the contents of the updated element to that array. To access it you have to create a function to loop through every result, push through a string, and return as trusted html. Here are some code snippets:

Here is the service

```
app.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var builds = {};
    builds.code = [];
    return builds;
});
```

I used this broadcast on the `<xmp>` element every time it was updated or a new one created

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('codeChange', { element: $element, changed: $element.html() });
```

Here is my directive

```
.directive('getcode', function(mySharedService) {
    return {
        controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $element, $sce,  mySharedService) {
            $scope.rawcode = function(){
                var output = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < mySharedService.code.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 1) {
                        output += mySharedService.code[i];
                    }
                }
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(output);
            }
            $scope.$on('codeChange', function($scope, args) {
                if (mySharedService.code.indexOf(args.element) == -1) {
                    mySharedService.code.push(args.element, args.changed);
                    indexed = mySharedService.code.indexOf(args.element) + 1;
                    mySharedService.code[indexed] = args.changed;
                }else {
                    indexed = mySharedService.code.indexOf(args.element) + 1;
                    mySharedService.code[indexed] = args.changed;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The reason for inserting both the `$element` and the `$element.html()` is because there are repeating elements, some of which contain the same html. You use the `+1` on the index of the element to access that `$element.html()` since the `$element` is always unique.